# Is Cantor's Diagonal Argument Dependent on Tertium Non Datur

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The standard presentation of Cantor's Diagonal argument on the uncountability of (0,1) starts with assuming the contrary through "reduction ad absurdum".  The intuitionist schools of mathematical regards "Tertium Non Datur" (bijection from N to R either exists or does not exist) untenable for infinite classes.

However, the argument can be modified by applying the diagonal argument to any function $f:N\to R$ thereby producing an element of $R$ not in the codomain of the function *f*.  Because this was applied to "any" function from $N$ to $R$, this shows the impossibility of an onto function from $N$ to R; ergo the uncountability of (0,1) independent of tertium non datur / excluded middle.

Is this conclusion/argument correct?

Comment: Yes. There is absolutely no need to present the argument as a proof by contradiction.

Comment: True. As you note, Cantor's diagonal argument is actually a construction: given any $f\colon \Bbb N\to \Bbb R$, it constructs a real $x$ which is not in the range of $f$. More generally it does this for any $f\colon X\to \mathcal{P}(X)$. In fact it seems to me the proof is intuitionistically valid.  We're trying to prove $\neg\exists f\,(...)$, and the proof constructively manufactures a counterexample from any alleged proof of $\exists f\,(...)$. It doesn't merely prove that it's impossible for the statement to be false, which would be an appeal to excluded middle.

Comment: Actually, there is a more serious use of the law of excluded middle in the diagonal argument when constructing the "new" real number. In fact, in the effective topos, Cantor's diagonal argument is simply false – the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ in that setting is not of greater cardinality than $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Any one of Cantor's diagonal number digits can definitely be computed, much like $e$ or $\pi$ or any other "computable" transcendental number.  These two other two quantities also do not have a place in the effective topos?